# MySQL Insert does not work in jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, insert

I am trying to make a register form using an insert query that has worked in a booking form that I previously made, but it doesn't seem to be inserting and it gives me this error message in the console log

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on page prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'bindRemove' coming from an external JS file.

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

This is from a PHP include

```
<?php

//This adds the connection file which has the details to connect to the database and what database to connect to
include_once('connection.php');

//Checks if the submit button is not set
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
exit;
}
    //Declared Variables
    $first = $_POST['fname'];
    $surname = $_POST['sname'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $postcode= $_POST['postcode'];
    $GPID= $_POST['Practice'];


    //Database Connection, this connects to the database using the connection.php
    $conn=ConnectionFactory::connect();

    //Insert Query
    $query="INSERT INTO `User`(`UserID`, `First_name`, `Surname`, `Username`, `Password`, `email`, `Image`, `Postcode`, `StoreID`, `DeptNo`, `AccessID`, `GPID`) VALUES (NULL, :fname, :sname, NULL, :password, :email, NULL, :postcode, 1, 1, 1, :GPID)";

    $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);

    //Binding values
    //$stmt->bindValue(':post', $Post);
    $stmt->bindValue(':fname', $first);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sname', $surname);

    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindValue(':postcode', $postcode);
    $stmt->bindValue(':GPID', $GPID);

    $affected_rows = $stmt->execute();

    //Message if insert is Successful
    if($affected_rows==1){
        print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"; 
        print "alert('Register Successful')"; 
        print "</script>";
        exit;
        }else{
        print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"; 
        print "alert('Unable to register at this moment')"; 
        print "</script>";
        exit;   
        }




    //Terminates the connection
            $conn=NULL;
?>
```

This is the form

```
 <section data-role="content">
    <h1>Register to be able to Book Appointments on the go</h1>
    <form id ="register" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])?>" method="POST">

        <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required>
        </fieldset>    

        <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="sname">Surname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" required>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="Password" name="password" id="password" required>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="Cpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="Password" name="Cpassword" id="Cpassword" required>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="postcode">Postcode:</label>
        <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" required>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
        <select id="Practice" name="Practice" class="required">
            <option value="null">Select a Practice</option>
            <option value="1">Guide Bridge Medical Centre</option>
            <option value="2">The University Health Centre</option>
            <option value="3">King Street Medical Centre</option>
            <option value="4">Mossley Medical Centre</option>
        </select>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="top" value="Register"/>
        <?php include 'registerInsert.php';?>
     </form>
```

Comment: Did you check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420567/uncaught-error-cannot-call-methods-on-page-prior-to-initialization-attempted-t ?

Comment: Try moving your $conn=null above those script tags.

Comment: @ChipDean moving the $conn=null sets off the error message I have in place

Comment: @AlexHerrett: looks to me like the problem is in your JavaScript code, but you haven't included any of it.

Comment: @nikc.org like i said its an external JS file <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: I've made some change and know i'm getting the error message coded in showing up, "Unable to register" bu the insert query is working on the database query simulator...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the line

```
 $affected_rows = $stmt->execute();
```

replace it with

```
 mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `User`(`UserID`, `First_name`, `Surname`, `Username`, `Password`, `email`, `Image`, `Postcode`, `StoreID`, `DeptNo`, `AccessID`, `GPID`) VALUES (NULL, :fname, :sname, NULL, :password, :email, NULL, :postcode, 1, 1, 1, :GPID)");
```

Comment: and would the affected row IF statement carry changes through that?

Comment: changed it and still getting nothing

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was the bind value but not quite sure what...

```
//Binding values

    $stmt->bindValue(':fname', $first);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sname', $surname);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindValue(':postcode', $postcode);
    $stmt->bindValue(':GPID', $GPID);
```

To get around it I used variables in the query

```
//Declared Variables
    $first = $_POST['fname'];
            $surname = $_POST['sname'];
    $username= "lemon";
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $Image= "1";
    $postcode= $_POST['postcode'];
    $StoreID= "1";
    $DeptNo= "1";
    $AccessID= "1";
    $GPID= $_POST['GPID'];

//Insert Query
    $query ="INSERT INTO `User`(`UserID`, `First_name`, `Surname`, `Username`, `Password`, `email`, `Image`, `Postcode`, `StoreID`, `DeptNo`, `AccessID`, `GPID`) VALUES (NULL, :fname, :sname, 'NULL',:password,:email, NULL,:postcode,'1','1','1',:GPID)";
```